# Sed through files without using for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed

I have a small script which basically generates a menu of all the scripts in my `~/scripts` folder and next to each of them displays a sentence describing it, that sentence being the third line within the script commented out. I then plan to pipe this into `fzf` or `dmenu` to select it and start editing it or whatever.

```sh
1 #!/bin/bash
2
3 # a script to do
```

So it would look something like this

```
foo.sh      a script to do X
bar.sh      a script to do Y
```

Currently I have it run a `for` loop over all the files in the scripts folder and then run `sed -n 3p` on all of them.

```sh
for i in $(ls -1 ~/scripts); do
    echo -n "$i"
    sed -n 3p "~/scripts/$i"
    echo 
done | column -t -s '#' | ...
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this that did not involve a for loop and only used `sed`. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `ls` here? You could do a `for file in ~/scripts/*;` and then simply `sed -n 3p "$file"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a loop that is parsing `ls` output + `sed`, you may try this `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR == 3 {
   f = FILENAME; sub(/^.*\//, "", f); print f, $0; nextfile
}' ~/scripts/* | column -t -s '#' | ...
```

Comment: I am not experienced with `awk` but would it be possible to display only the filename without the full path within the above `awk` command itself, ie without relying on an eternal program like `basename` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a more efficient way, but no, it doesn't only use `sed`. This is probably a silly optimization for your use case though, but it may be worthwhile nonetheless.

The inefficiency is that you're using `ls` to read the directory and then parse its output. For large directories, that causes lots of overhead for keeping that list in memory even though you only traverse it once. Also, it's not done correctly, consider filenames with special characters that the shell interprets.

The more efficient way is to use `find` in combination with its `-exec` option, which starts a second program with each found file in turn.

BTW: If you didn't rely on line numbers but maybe a tag to mark the description, you could also use `grep -r`, which avoids an additional process per file altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn '1h;3{H;g;s/\n/ /p}' ~/scripts/*
```

Use the `-s` option to reset the line number addresses for each file.

Copy line 1 to the hold space.

Append line 3 to the hold space.

Swap the hold space for the pattern space.

Replace the newline with a space and print the result.

All files in the directory `~/scripts` will be processed.

N.B. You may wish to replace the space delimiter by a tab or pipe the results to the `column` command.